# Get text from brackets in string

Tags: php, arrays, match

I have a string like

```
This is [string] and its [text] and [stuff]
```

I need to get text within `[]` into an array like

```
array('string', 'text', 'stuff');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about nested brackets? But if it is only this simple format, you should get what you need with a regular expression:

```
$matches = array()
preg_match_all('/\[([^]]+)]/', $subject, $matches);
```

`$matches` is a multi-dimensional array containing all matches. See the documentation of [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for an explanation of its format.

The regex captures anything between two brackets that is not a bracket and has at least one character. Breakdown:

- `\[`: a literal opening bracket
- `(`: start of capture group

  - `[^]]`: not a closing bracket
  - `+`: one or more
- `)`: end of capture group
- `]`: a literal closing bracket

Comment: Does this put them into `$matches[1]` or does it create a single array using preg_match_all?

Comment: @Popnoodles: The former.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : https://eval.in/85383
**TRY THIS:**

```
$p ="/\[.*?\]/s";

$str = ' "This is [string] and its [text] and [stuff]".';

preg_match_all($p,$str,$r);

$re =array();
$arr = array("[","]");
foreach($r[0] as $s){
  $s = str_replace($arr,"'",$s);
  array_push($re,$s );
}
print_r($re);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the substr solution:

```
$array = array();
$count = substr_count($myString,'[');
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
 $firstOccurenceInit = strpos($myString, '[');
 $firstOccurenceEnd = strpos($myString, ']');
 $array[] = substr($myString,$firstOccurenceInit,$firstOccurenceEnd);
 $myString = substr($myString,$firstOccurenceEnd);
}
```

This is only a test. It may works or not. Is an example.